# Symfony serializer : discriminate on structure (or data type)

Tags: symfony, serialization, discriminator

I run into an issue when I try to deserialize some JSON with an interface.
JSON data structure is changing and there's no scalar data to rely on. Note that I'm not able to modify the JSON and that I am not able to ask for one structure or another.
As I did not find any way to handle mapping on data type, I thought I would inject a virtual value during normalize process.

Unfortunately it does not seem to be possible, the discriminator seems to be triggered before data is added.

Am I missing something ?

### A sample of code to illustrate my problem

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\DiscriminatorMap;

/**
 * @DiscriminatorMap(typeProperty="type", mapping={
 *    "string"="Test\Bar1",
 *    "array"="Test\Bar2"
 * })
 */
interface Foo
{

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

class Bar1 implements Foo
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $foo;

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

class Bar2 implements Foo
{

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $type;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public $foo;

}
```

```php
<?php

namespace Test;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;

class FooNormalizer extends ObjectNormalizer
{
    public function normalize($data, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $data         = $this->normalizer->normalize($data, $format, $context);
        $data['type'] = is_string($data['foo'])
            ? 'string'
            : 'array';

        return $data;
    }
}
```

So when I launch my test:

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationReader;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\PhpDocExtractor;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\ClassDiscriminatorFromClassMetadata;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Factory\ClassMetadataFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Mapping\Loader\AnnotationLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\MetadataAwareNameConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

use Test\Foo;
use Test\FooNormalizer;

try {

    $data = [];

    $data[] = <<<JSON
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "hey"
    }
}
JSON;

    $data[] = <<<JSON
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": ["hey", "ho"]
    }
}
JSON;

    $class_metadata_factory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader())),

    $serializer = new Serializer(
            [
                new FooNormalizer(
                    class_metadata_factory,
                    new MetadataAwareNameConverter(
                        $class_metadata_factory
                    ),
                    null,
                    new PhpDocExtractor(),
                    new ClassDiscriminatorFromClassMetadata($class_metadata_factory)
                )
            ],
            ['json' => new JsonEncoder()]
        );


    foreach ($data as $d) {

        $rs = $serializer->deserialize($d, Foo::class, 'json');

    }


} catch (\Exception $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

I get the exception:

> Type property "type" not found for the abstract object "Foo"

Did anybody already had this kind of issue and found a way to handle it ?

Comment: Hm, regarding to the doctrine documentation: `The @InheritanceType and @DiscriminatorColumn must be specified on the topmost class that is part of the mapped entity hierarchy.` So, I'm not sure that it will work in the interface, try to implement it as an Abstract class

Comment: Yeah, did read that too, the interface seems to be considered as the topmost class too (but I did this test with an abstract class too, issue is the same)

Comment: Also, are you sure that your DiscriminatorMap annotation is right? https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: Annotations seems fine with my version, I'm using v4.2 and followed the guideline here: https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/components/serializer.html#serializing-interfaces-and-abstract-classes

Unfortunately this component is not documented a lot.